# Amazon S3 object modify/replace

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XceeB.png)Is it possible to clean S3 object inside S3 using lambda?

1) I have python script which clean the file data -

```
import re
import os
sourcepath = os.listdir('InputFiles/')
for file in sourcepath:
    inputfile = 'InputFiles/'+ file
    print ('Conversion is going for :'+ inputfile)
    with open(inputfile,'r') as inputfile:
         filedata = inputfile.read()
    freq = 0
    destinationpath = 'Outputfile/'+ file
    filedata = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9\n\.]', ' ', filedata)
    with open (destinationpath,'w') as file:
         file.write(filedata)
    print filedata
```

Can you write this logic inside AWS lambda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.  Please check out the Boto3 S3 reference (http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3.html#s3-guide):

Here's a little bit to get you started:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
your_bucket = s3.Bucket('name_of_your_bucket')

for item_in_bucket in your_bucket.objects.all():
     # do stuff
```

A few things to keep in mind:

- make sure that the role the lambda function is running under has access to S3
- make sure you increase your lambda timeout configuration (5 minutes max) so that you will have enough time to clean all the objects within the bucket.
- if you are exceeding 5 minutes you could look into using AWS State Machines with Step Functions with modular lambda operations to clean and store the files.